# Issue getting correct results from LINQ query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am writing a query in LINQ, but having issues getting correct record from database. When I execute LINQ query, I get duplicate records. Please see below records with duplicate results in JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "serverId": 1,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server1",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.1",
    "vip": "10.1.1.5",
    "url": "www.testapp.com",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 1,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server1",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.1",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 2,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server2",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.2",
    "vip": "10.1.1.5",
    "url": "www.testapp.com",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 2,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server2",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.2",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 3,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric UI",
    "serverName": "Server3",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "172.16.1.1",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain2",
    "network": "DMZ 1",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 3,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric UI",
    "serverName": "Server3",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "172.16.1.1",
    "vip": "10.1.1.6",
    "url": "www.testappui.com",
    "domain": "Domain2",
    "network": "DMZ 1",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 4,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric UI",
    "serverName": "Server4",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "172.16.1.2",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain2",
    "network": "DMZ 1",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 4,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric UI",
    "serverName": "Server4",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "172.16.1.2",
    "vip": "10.1.1.6",
    "url": "www.testappui.com",
    "domain": "Domain2",
    "network": "DMZ 1",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 1002,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server5",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "10.1.1.5",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "INT",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "serverId": 1003,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "server6",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "10.1.1.6",
    "vip": "",
    "url": "",
    "domain": "Domain1",
    "network": "Internal Harden",
    "typeName": "Application",
    "environmentName": "INT",
    "status": "Active"
  }
]
```

Here is the query I am using in my ASPT.NET Core application:

```
var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
    join sr in _context.ServersResourceGroup on rg.Id equals sr.ResourceGroup_id
    join rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment on sr.Environment_id equals rge.Environment_id into lrges
    from lrge in lrges.Where(r => r.ResourceGroup_id == sr.ResourceGroup_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in _context.Servers on sr.Server_id equals s.Id
    join e in _context.Environments on sr.Environment_id equals e.Id
    join a in _context.Applications on rg.Application_Id equals a.Id
    join d in _context.Domains on s.Domain_Id equals d.Id
    join t in _context.Types on rg.Type_Id equals t.Id
    join o in _context.OperatingSystems on s.OperatingSystem_Id equals o.Id
    join n in _context.NetworkZones on s.NetworkZone_Id equals n.Id
    join stat in _context.Status on s.Status.Id equals stat.Id
    where a.Name.ToLower() == applicationName.ToLower()
    select new SearchListViewModel()
    {
        serverId = s.Id,
        serverName = s.ServerName,
        aliasName = s.Alias,
        domain = d.Name,
        environmentName = e.Name,
        network = n.Name,
        os = o.OSVersion,
        ipAddress = s.IPAddress,
        vip = lrge == null ? string.Empty : lrge.VIP,
        url = lrge == null ? string.Empty : lrge.EndPointURL,
        typeName = t.Name,
        applicationName = a.Name,
        resourceName = rg.Name,
        status = stat.Name
    };

return query.ToList();
```

Also, here is the native SQL query that just works fine.

```
SELECT s.ServerName, rg.Name as ResourceGroup, e.Name as Env,  
rge.EndPointURL, rge.VIP  
FROM ResourceGroup as rg  
JOIN ServersResourceGroup as srg on rg.Id = srg.ResourceGroup_id  
JOIN Servers as s on srg.Server_id = s.Id  
JOIN Environments as e on srg.Environment_id = e.Id  
LEFT JOIN ResourceGroupEnvironment as rge on srg.Environment_id = rge.Environment_id and rg.Id = rge.ResourceGroup_Id
```

Not sure if my LINQ query is wrong, but I am trying to accomplish above native query in LINQ,

Here is my entity model to help understand requirement:

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you,

Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't see any duplicate in your result (every "result set" is different).

Now, you have something strange in your left join, using a `Where` clause on a left joined item.

```
join rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment on sr.Environment_id equals rge.Environment_id into lrges
from lrge in lrges.Where(r => r.ResourceGroup_id == sr.ResourceGroup_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I'd rather do a join using multiple conditions (using `new`)

```
join rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment on new{sr.Environment_id, sr.ResourceGroup_id} equals new{ rge.Environment_id, rge.ResourceGroup_id} into lrges
from lrge in lrges.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: It worked. I was searching for days to find out how to use multiple conditions and it now makes sense. Thank you very much. :)